# iOS: I have a issue in storyboard by fit the imageView.

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, storyboard

In storyboard, my `imageView` is fixed width and height.

And in storyboard `View` -> `Mode`: usually has `3` kind of image fit mode to choose, but they not what I want. I want to have a clip mode, which the `imageView` can show a part of image content, and it will not shape change.
How can I do that in storyboard or in code?

There are some picture I cut out in `simulator`.

```
Aspect fill mode
```

[image: Aspect fill mode]

```
Scale To Fill mode
```

[image: Scale To Fill mode]

```
Aspect Fit mode
```

[image: Aspect Fit mode]

```
Center mode
```

[image: Center mode]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, if I understand you correctly but, you can tell the image view to clip it's contents. In storyboard, this is done like shown in the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: BTW,I have a question , if I set `imageView.contentMode` in code instead of `storyboard`, how can I set `clipSubViews`?

Comment: I found the way to set in code:

`imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;`

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

If in `storyboard`, we can resolve this by @dasdom 's answer which I voted up.

If in code, I found the way to adapt `imageView`:

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```